# Flutter Internationalization: How to break down .arb files into separate files

Tags: flutter, dart, internationalization

I'm following the Flutter [Internationalizing Flutter apps](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization), and I'm not seeing a way to break down the `.arb` files. Is it possible to have my `app_en.arb`? It would be much better if I could break down the content like this

```
buttons_en.arb
messages_en.arb
```

And so forth

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had also searched for this, but did not come up with any results. But what helped me was to write comments and to highlight them with an extension. It now looks like this and that is in my opinion also okay:

[image: arb comment immage]

See this guide if you want to implement it: https://medium.com/codex/flutter-writing-comments-in-arb-files-8d113f10e4b9